# PHPUnit code coverage

Tags: magento2, phpunit

I am trying to generate the code coverage report in HTML format for a module I am writing so I can work out where I need to improve coverage.

Normally when I run tests for my module I use the following command:

`vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist vendor/vendorname/m2-module-name/`

I tried to generate the report using the following command:

`vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist --coverage-html ./report vendor/vendorname/m2-module-name/`

[image: PHPUnit HTML output]

As you can see PHPUnit is generating the report for the setup module.

Does anybody know how to run code coverage on Magento 2?

I have also tried editing the phpunit.xml.dist to include the following line but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
<logging>
    <!--coverage_html_placeholder-->
        <log type="coverage-html" target="/usr/share/nginx/html/test-reports/coverage" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" highlight="true"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working.

I copied `dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist` to `dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml` and used the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.1/phpunit.xsd"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="./framework/bootstrap.php"
        >
    <testsuite name="Magento Unit Tests">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">../../../vendor/vendorname/m2-module-name/Test/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <php>
        <ini name="date.timezone" value="America/Los_Angeles"/>
        <ini name="xdebug.max_nesting_level" value="200"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Then I ran the phpunit command:

`vendor/bin/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml --coverage-html ./report vendor/vendorname/m2-module-name/`

And it produced the output for the vendor directory instead:

[image: PHPUnit HTML output]

Answer (score 2):

To generate code coverage report in HTML format for your custom module, run below command from your Magento root directory:

```
php ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist app/code/[vendor Name]/[Module Name]/ --coverage-html coverage
```

Also, You can generate code coverage report for the specific file. To generate code coverage for the specific file you need to give full path of your test case file.

```
php ./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml.dist app/code/[vendor Name]/[Module Name]/Test/Unit/Model/[File Name] --coverage-html coverage
```